# Parameter @machine in SQL Server query slow

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have created a stored procedure with the following parameters:

```
@id int, @machine varchar(50)
```

The stored procedure queries 2 tables with a left join. Table 1 has 2,500,000 rows and table 2 has 750,000 rows.

The execution of the stored procedure takes about 72 seconds.

When I change name of param `@machine` to `@machineID`, the stored procedure takes about 10 seconds.

Do you know why this is so?

Comment: May be post some code from the SP.

Comment: Are you sure it not just that SQL has the data for the previous query in memory already? What happens if you run the query with parameter machineID, and  then change it back to Machine and run it again? Is it still slow?